# How to properly set up jaxrs client dependencies?

Tags: java, api, maven, dependencies, jax-rs

I'm trying to use jax-rs 2.0 for an existing java client code (java 8), it didn't previously support maven (and i do not wanted to use maven or any similar frameworks) but the jax-rs "client" needed a dependency for org.glassfish.jersy.client, so i went out and read about dependencies in general and frameworks which i'm new to.

added maven framework to my project, and edited the pom.xml file for dependencies :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>CVT Sale Data Manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersy.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersy.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersy-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

and this is part of the restapi code:

```
package api;

import javax.ws.rs.client.*;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class RestApi {

    private static Client client;
    private static WebTarget baseTarget;            //base url

    public RestApi()
    {
        //changed on the server
        ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();


        baseTarget = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api");
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    }
```

somehow i'm still getting the same error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
    at api.RestApi.<init>(RestApi.java:27)
    at Launcher.initSingeltons(Launcher.java:36)
    at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:29)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:185)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:70)
    ... 14 more
Exception running application Launcher
```

I'm very new to these dependencies type of thing so its very much possible that i have a very obvious error that i do not know about, i apologize in advance if that is the case.

Comment: How are you running your program? Are you sure the dependencies are on the class path?

Comment: i'm running the program from Intellij's run command, i'm not sure what a class path is. there is a pom.xml file which i assume that would handle the paths?

Comment: Instead of ClientBuilder, try to use JerseyClientBuilder and see if it compiles

Comment: @PaulSamsotha JerseyClientBuilder does not seem to exist in javax
should i use another specific library instead ? links to it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the jaxrs-ri and add [jersey-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client) (org,glassfish.jersey.core)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha it still does not seem to exist in my libraries, im using javax.ws.rs do i need a library for that ? i still don't quite understand how pom.xml and maven work.

Comment: Copy and paste [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.31) and refresh your project to force the download of the dependency. How it works is that there is a central repository for jars (dependencies) and you declare them in the pom.xml, and they get downloaded (if not already in your local repo). If it's already in your local repository, it gets the dependency from there. Your local repository is in ${HOME}/.m2/repository. Brief summary of how it works.

Comment: With Intellij, you can set u your project to where once you declare the dependency, it will automatically download. If the project configuration is not set, you will need to manually trigger a download. It should ask you if you want to set this property when you start declaring dependencies. Or you can just run `mvn package` from the command line. There are many different ways

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221113/discussion-between-sam-and-paul-samsotha).